# Sitecore CDP certification question patterns sample of scenario based questions

Tags: cdp, sitecore-personalize

I am planning to attend `Sitecore CDP` & `Personalize certification` exam. I went through the advised certification materials. I came to know the question are scenario based not the concept based. Can any one who already attended `CDP` certification share me sample question to focus more on needed section of material/ training.

Comment: This article contains question notes from CDP certification and can be helpful for you: https://navansitecorenotes.blogspot.com/2021/12/sitecore-cdp-boxever-notes.html

Comment: Got this info from slack - use  interactive APIs, just by making a "DELETE" verb request to https://api.boxever.com/v2/guests/{GUESTREF} it should return a 200 Success.  You should verify that this is working correctly.  It may take up to 24 hours for the Guest to be removed.  Also authentication is the same as other Interactive APIs using Basic Auth with username/password being the client key/access token.

Answer (score 0):

https://navansitecorenotes.blogspot.com/2021/12/sitecore-cdp-boxever-notes.html   
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGLMDlItv58
https://learning.sitecore.com/partners/learn/course/389/play

Try search through developer portal which enriched with Sitecore-search now:
https://developer-portal-git-sitecore-search-sitecoretechnicalmarketing.vercel.app/search?q=sitecore%20CDP%20new%20sdk

I got to know there are new learnings, please look into these too:

**Sitecore CDP and Personalize Fundamentals – Technical**

Experiments Module Series

Setting up experiments

Interpreting experiment results

Personalized Experiences Module Series

Real-time audiences in Sitecore Personalize

Decisioning Module Series

Programmables and decision templates in Sitecore Personalize